# loop at sql call

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, sqlite

thank you so much in advance.

I am running into a loop, and not sure how to break out of it here.

This is the code:

```
- (BOOL) next {

int rc;
BOOL retry;
int numberOfRetries = 0;
do {
    retry = NO;

    rc = sqlite3_step(statement.statement);

    if (SQLITE_BUSY == rc) {
        // this will happen if the db is locked, like if we are doing an update or insert.
        // in that case, retry the step... and maybe wait just 10 milliseconds.
        retry = YES;
        usleep(20);

        if ([parentDB busyRetryTimeout] && (numberOfRetries++ > [parentDB busyRetryTimeout])) {

            NSLog(@"%s:%d Database busy (%@)", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [parentDB databasePath]);
            NSLog(@"Database busy");
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (SQLITE_DONE == rc || SQLITE_ROW == rc) {
        // all is well, let's return.
    }
    else if (SQLITE_ERROR == rc) {
        NSLog(@"Error calling sqlite3_step (%d: %s) rs", rc, sqlite3_errmsg([parentDB sqliteHandle]));
        break;
    } 
    else if (SQLITE_MISUSE == rc) {
        // uh oh.
        NSLog(@"Error calling sqlite3_step (%d: %s) rs", rc, sqlite3_errmsg([parentDB sqliteHandle]));
        break;
    }
    else {
        // wtf?
        NSLog(@"Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (%d: %s) rs", rc, sqlite3_errmsg([parentDB sqliteHandle]));
        break;
    }

} while (retry);
```

Error is happening at `rc = sqlite3_step(statement.statement);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What value is `sqlite3_step` returning? Put in a `NSLog` statement right before your `sqlite3_step` (and display the `numberOfRetries`). You later imply that it's hanging at the `sqlite3_step` function call, which seems unlikely.
2. More likely, this routine is repeatedly calling `sqlite3_step` (e.g. if the database is busy and `[parentDB busyRetryTimeout]` is 0, this function would never end (or at least until the database contention was resolved). That's the only obvious problem that's leaping out at me, but it requires a confluence of multiple factors.
3. Why is your database busy? Trying to use it in a background queue? Personally, for my apps that require background database operation, I create a separate [serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) in [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) queue for my database operations which, because it's serial, ensures that there is no database contention. Incidentally, if you ever want to get out of the weeds of SQLite programming, [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a wonderful wrapper, and it has a `FMDatabaseQueue` which takes care of all of this for you. If my conjecture of point 2 is right, you need to fix that first, but in general, FMDB simplifies background operations on databases.

Comment: very detailed answer, thank you.  I am pretty new to this whole sqllite business.  Less than 10 months coding in general, and with xcode, so I appreciate your help.  The ns log message showed 0...

Comment: What do you mean "`NSLog` message showed 0"? That you logged `numberOfRetries` and got "0"? Or that `busyRetryTimeout` was "0"? And if you insert another `NSLog` after the `sqlite3_step` (or set a breakpoint there), do you get to that line of code? If you want our assistance, you need to do some detailed debugging here (set [breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW18) and single step through this routine) and tell us what you find.

Comment: See [Step Through Code in the Source Editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW27) for information how to step through code after setting a breakpoint and running.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `statement.statement` it should be just `rc = sqlite3_step(statement);`

I'll suggest check the db before the step statement, check it at the prepare statement itself.

```
 rc      = sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, 0);
```